# If a function is biholomorphic, why is its $n$th power an $n$-to-$1$ function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an injective holomorphic function (so a biholomorphism). Say $f(0)=0$. Define $F(z)=f(z)^n$. Then why is $F$ an $n$-to-$1$ function on $U \backslash 0$?

I am guessing this is something very simple, but I have not understood this.

Answer (score 1):

Take some nonzero $w_0 \in F(U)$ and notice it has $n$ different complex $n$'th roots:

- There is at least one thanks to the fundamental theorem of algebra - the polynomial $w^n - w_0$ reduces to a product of linear factors over $\Bbb{C}$.
- All the roots are different from each other, because there are $n$ different [roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), and you get the other roots by multiplying by the different roots of unity.

For any $w$ which is an $n$'th root of $w_0$ there is a unique $z \in U$ such that $f(z) = w$, and then $F(z) = w_0$. So the equation $F(z) = w_0$ has exactly $n$ solutions.

Comment: Ah that made things very clear. Thank you!